# Identify this dragonfly with orange body and orange wings?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

The photo shows a red dragonfly on top (in front of [some hot pink snail eggs](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/92166/27918)) but an **orange dragonfly with orange and perhaps translucent(?) wings** near the bottom. This is the best resolution I could get. While the red one is easy to photograph (see [Identify these two big, beautiful dragonflies in Taiwan?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/95610/27918)) this orange species is really jittery and difficult to approach.

I believe I have seen dozens of them in an isolated grassy patch in a parking lot, but they never landed and I could not capture a photo or see them clearly, but today this one was "available" for a photoshoot.

The orange dragonfly's body is **about 4 to 5 cm long, the location is Hsinchu county Taiwan.** That's all I've got, except that the last centimeter or so of the wings appear to be almost transparent.

[image: orange dragonfly with orange wings in Hsinchu county, Taiwan]

Answer (score 3):

These seem to both be *Neurothemis taiwanensis*.

On iNaturalist, if you search for dragonflies in Taiwan, it finds 104 species observed and submitted, and this Neurothemis taiwanensis is the most popularly-submitted species.

Browsing the gallery of photos in their database shows both red and orange varieties. If we filter the sex on just males, we see mainly deep-red ones:

[image]

...and filtering on just females yields mainly orange ones but also some red ones:

https://inaturalist.ca/taxa/503081-Neurothemis-taiwanensis/browse_photos?term_id=9&term_value_id=10&place_id=7887

Comment: Wow! Very nice, Yes I see that now. Okay I will now try to figure out how to use the inaturalist.ca site's features. Thank you very much!